# VueJS and Staticfile Buildpack configuration: Remove the URL hashtag?

Tags: nginx, vue-router, cloud-foundry

I am using the Staticfile buildpack for a single page application using VueJS (JavaScript framework). I want clean URLs without the hashtag (e.g, /#/page1). So, all I have to do is add the following line in `Staticfile`

```
pushstate: enabled
```

This works in my tests. However, do I still need to add the `history` mode to Vue-Router?

I am confused because not doing the latter seems to be fine...

Thought I'd double check here.

Comment: What is this static file build pack that you are talking about here?

Comment: @RuChernChong It is this: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html

Comment: I know this was 10 months ago and didn't get any traction, but did you ever clarify and end up using Static Buildpack with a VueJS SPA?